# If an $H\leq G$ has an irreducible representation of dimension $d$, then show $G$ has an irreducible representation of atleast dimension $d$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, and let $\rho:H\rightarrow GL(V )$ be an
irreducible representation of dimension $d$. Prove that there is an irreducible
representation of $G$ whose dimension is at least $d$.

This is a homework problem I would appreciate it if someone could give me a hint on how to begin. I am assuming I have to apply properties of induced representation, but I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: are you familiar with induced representations?